# Query to return rows where column does not contain a certain substring

Tags: sql-server-2005, where-clause

Is there something I can put in my WHERE clause to only select fields from a column where that field does not contain a certain string. In this case, I am looking through to make sure the codes in this particular field do not have a "cs" in it. The code could be something like cs023 or bg425, just to give you a little bit more of an idea what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use

`WHERE [column] NOT LIKE '%cs%'`

Replace [column] with your column name.

Comment: Cheers! I thought about that, but I wasn't sure if it would only work if that was the only value in the field (like, the column only consisted of "cs").

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit, it'll work just fine in that instance. There are more ways to do it. For example if you know for sure that "cs" is at the beginning of the string, you can do `NOT LIKE 'cs%'`.

Comment: turns out cs was in the middle of the string - but that worked just fine :D

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of alternatives (for folks who like VB's InStr() or JS' .indexOf() type syntax).

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('cs', [column]) = 0;
```

...or...

```
WHERE PATINDEX('%cs%', [column]) = 0;
```

You might also want to deal with `NULL` values:

```
WHERE COALESCE([column], '') NOT LIKE '%cs%';
```